# new to android - downloaded android project from git, imported into eclipse and everything looks wierd

Tags: java, android, eclipse

please look at this screen shot:

[image]

please look in src folder, here are some questions:

1. what do these "honeycomb" icons stand for
2. Why didnt the author simply just create class.java files, rather he put them into these "honeycombs"?
3. what is prajwol.app.qms

I tried to look through eclipse documentation but could not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Those are not `honeycomb`. Its called packages. You can find java class in different packages. Packages are defined to solve the problem complexity and package name should describe what functionality the java classes provides which is in it.

Answer (score 0):

1. "honeycomb" icons stand for **package** ex. stack.over.com
2. creating different or more than one package in a single app usually means it has more than one function. like if you are making an app that has games in it it's easier to make two packager for each game so it can be clear for you and easier to control and code.
3. prajwol.app.qms is queue my status.

Comment: prajwol.app.qms is queue my status? what does that mean ?

Comment: it's something about your app, I found it online.